# Can I make an absolutely positioned stack of divs stay in the flow?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making a simple jquery slideshow that changes the opacity of divs that are positioned absolutely on top of each other.  My problem is because they're positioned absolutely, they're not in the flow anymore but I need them to be.  So I need one of three things.

Find a way to stack divs without using position absolute. or

Find a way to put absolutely positioned divs back in the flow. or

Find a way to make the slideshow without using stacked divs.

html:

```
<body>
I come before<br />
<div id="box_foot">
  <div id="tests">
    <div class="testimony" style="opacity: 1;">
      <div class="bluequote">One</div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimony">
        <div class="bluequote">Multiple lines<br />Multiple lines<br /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimony">
      <div class="bluequote">Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimony">
      <div class="bluequote">Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimony">
      <div class="bluequote">Four</div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimony">
      <div class="bluequote">Five</div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimony">
      <div class="bluequote">Six</div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimony">
      <div class="bluequote">Seven</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
I come after<br />
</body>
```

css:

```
#box_foot .testimony {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
}
```

slideshow function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 1;
    var $slides = $('.testimony');
    var speed = 1000;

    setInterval(rotQuote,speed);

    function rotQuote(){    
        if(count < $slides.length){
            $('.testimony:nth-child(' + count + ')').animate({opacity:0},1000);
            count++;
            $('.testimony:nth-child(' + count + ')').animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
        } else {
            $('.testimony:nth-child(' + count + ')').animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
            count = 1;
            $('.testimony:nth-child(' + count + ')').animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
        }
    }

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P48yA/

I can set a fixed height, but this doesn't allow for flexibility in the layout/responsiveness.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated!**

Why not apply a CSS class and animation?

This keeps the elements as part of the document flow- just compacts them to nothing when they arent being 'shown'

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/P48yA/7/)

```
#box_foot .testimony {
    position:relative;
    opacity:0;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:opacity 1s ease-in;
}
#box_foot .testimony.show {
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    -webkit-animation:fader 1s ease-in;
    animation:fader 1s ease-in;
}
@keyframes fader {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fader {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

Adjusted jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 1;
    var $slides = $('.testimony');
    var speed = 1000;

    setInterval(rotQuote, speed);

    function rotQuote() {
        if (count < $slides.length) {
            $('.testimony:nth-child(' + count + ')').removeClass('show');
            count++;
            $('.testimony:nth-child(' + count + ')').addClass('show');
        } else {
            $('.testimony:nth-child(' + count + ')').removeClass('show');
            count = 1;
            $('.testimony:nth-child(' + count + ')').addClass('show');
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the parent container of the absolutely positioned divs have `position: relative;` and that will position them absolutely from the top-left of the parent container instead of the body, then just give the parent div a fixed height that's big enough for all of the divs contents to show, and this will fix the problem. It will be responsive because the parent container will be in the flow, and the div's that fade in and out will be positioned relative to the parent.